# CLion debugger doesn't work with MinGW and GDB

Tags: c, debugging, clion

I've been trying to debug a program of mine in CLion and couldn't figure out why none of the breakpoints that I set were hit. I was using MinGW as a toolchain. After I switched to the Visual Studio toolchain, the debugger mysteriously worked. Why is this and how can I fix this issue? I need the debugger to work with MinGW. Here are some more details of my set toolchains:
I wrote this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    a += 1;
    printf("Hello, %d!\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

And I set a breakpoint at every line after the main() declaration. Here is the default CMake file that was generated:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(practice_1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(practice_1 main.c)
```

And here is the MinGW toolchain set:

[image]

When I run this in CLion in debug mode the debugger doesn't work. It just goes straight to the end, printing that message in the console.

If I set the toolchain with the Visual Studio setting it all works. So I do this:

[image]

And now I can use the Visual Studio debugger. It hits the breakpoints and I can debug my program. But I need to use the other setting. How can I solve this issue and use the GDB debugger? I tried adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283911/15033320) in the CMake file but it didn't work.

This is the build text I get in the console after rebuilding all:

```
====================[ Clean | Debug ]===========================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "D:\Practice\practice_1\cmake-build-debug" --target clean -- -j 9

Clean finished

====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "D:\Practice\practice_1\cmake-build-debug" --target all -- -j 9
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/practice_1.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable practice_1.exe
[100%] Built target practice_1
```

Build finished

Comment: Have you checked the build log to verify that the `-g` switch is used?  Posting the build log (from _rebuild all_) might be useful.

Comment: @Clifford I'm not exactly sure how to do that. I found the button of *Rebuild all* and hit it and then the project got rebuilt and this message was shown: `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "D:\Practice\practice_1\cmake-build-debug" --target all -- -j 9`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I am not familiar with CLion or even CMake. What I would want to see is the compiler and linker command lines and diagnostics issued during the build.  I would avoid any IDE or build system that hides this raw information from you. Some IDEs hide this stuff in a log file rather than presenting it in a window. Perhaps in the terminal window (looking at screenshots of CLion)?

Comment: @Clifford I added the full text from the console at the end of the question. That is everything shown when I rebuild all. Hope it helps. But let's say that I don't have that `-g` switch turned on. How can I actually use it?

Comment: the _"I tried adding this"_ link adds the -g switch; I was looking for a means of verifying that it was actually doing it. Whatever is happening under the hood at _"Building C object ..."_ is what you need access to.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem, I changed the CMake configuration adding the flag `-g` as follows**

[image]

It allowed the debugger to work fine

[image]

#### Hope it works